# How do we enforce a valid way of opening a new window?

Tags: xhtml, hyperlink, new-window

XHTML 1.1 has no such attribute `target` on anchors, well, it works - yes, but it's not valid.

So, how do we open a link in new window in a valid way?

Comment: Not using XHTML 1.1 would be a good start. It provides few benefits over HTML 4.01 and fewer over the XML serialisation of HTML 5.

Comment: There is a problem with HTML5 not being the "standard" yet. Any good reference on XHTML 1.1 over HTML 4.01?

Comment: It is XML and thus can be used with XML tools. That's the only benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's posible  (because target="_blank". has been depracated)  to open a new window using only XHTML but there is a way by adding a bit of javascript.I have been using this method for a while now and it works well.Have a look at this link:

http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/08/30/how-to-make-a-link-open-in-a-new-window-with-xhtml/